# How to fix segue problems between ViewControllers using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, back-button

I got 3 view controllers. On first page user defines some variables and when he executes it, it goes to second page with segue.identifier. On second page a time counter starts and an item price is decreasing over time. Whenever user uses buy button, the program prints on third page item number, updated time and price. Then if user uses show items button, he will go to the third page and see printed lines. However, I put a navigation bar with a back button on top of the third page, when I use back button, it crashes.

Here is my question: How can I fix it without changing updated price and time counter? With segue.identifier? If yes, how?

Comment: Can you provide the error message printed in the log while crash?

Comment: I really didn't get what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to go back from 3rd to 2nd controller?

Comment: @KutayDemireren definitely. I just want to go back

Comment: You are talking about segues, so I assume you use storyboard ?

Comment: yes I use storyboard with 3 viewcontrollers

Comment: @Aras Serdaroğlu - What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you have to do. Select the 2nd view controller, go to the edit from top and follow the path: edit -> embed in -> navigation controller.

This will automatically adds the navigation bars and back button to the 3rd controller.

Hope this helps .

Comment: my first segue between first and second view controllers become a different segue between first and third. I didn't get it why it shows like that in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your own `UINavigationBar`. Like **Kutay Demireren** said, you want to embed your first view controller in a `UINavigationController`, and then the segues will work by pushing each destination controller onto the navigation controller's stack.

Comment: After performing what he said, embed navigation controller got an automatic segue from initial view controller and it crashes. My goal:

FVC -> SVC <-> TVC. However, after returning back to SVC from TVC, SVC calculations should be updated over time

Comment: The "automatic segue" from the NC to FVC is a root-view controller segue, and that's as it should be. I would need to see your code, error message, and/or storyboard to figure out why it crashes. But for the second part of your comment, when returning to SVC from TVC, you need to implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` in TVC, and when the segue's identifier equals whatever string you set in the segue from TVC to SVC, have it tell the SVC to update its timer.